# How To Use a Different sized Category Image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hoping someone can help.

I'm in the process of building a WooCommerce site and I've run into a problem with category images.

When you click on the shop there is a page with various category thumbnails. When you click on the thumbnail you are taken to a page with products relating to that category.

What I'm looking for is to then use the same category image from the previous page as the header. The issue is is that the image is at a different size intended i.e full size.

I have stipulated a size called feat-img within functions.php but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Here is the code I'm using to display the category image:

```
<?php
            if (is_product_category()){
                global $wp_query;
                $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
                echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
            }
        ?>
```

Any help would appreciated as to how I use the 'feat-img' size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First define in functions.php like this

```
add_image_size('300pxSize',300,300);
add_image_size( 'full-width-ratio', 600, 9999 );
add_image_size( 'full-width-crop', 600, 300, true );
add_image_size( 'full-width-crop-h200', 600, 200, true );

//get featured image
function f_image($id,$width="300pxSize") {
    $postThumbnailId = get_post_thumbnail_id( $id );
    $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $postThumbnailId, $width);

    return  $imgsrc[0];
}
// Check if post has image
function hasFeaturedImage($id) {
    $fImg = f_image($id);
    if($fImg)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then call in your page (single.php for example)  like this:

```
  <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(hasFeaturedImage(get_the_ID())) : ?>
      <div class="single-post-image">
        <img src="<?php echo f_image(get_the_ID(),"full-width-crop"); ?>" alt="">
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query(); ?>
```